# Spring annotation @Retryable - how to set an interceptor

Tags: java, spring, spring-rabbit, spring-retry

I am using a `@Retryable` annotation on a method in a `@Service`class

```
@Service
@EnableRetry 
public class PushService {

    @Retryable(maxAttempts=5)
    public Result pushIt(myMessage messageIn) {
        ...
    }
}
```

and it works like a charme: I am getting a message directly from RabbitMQ, it is not acknowledged until either there is no error, or the number of attempts reach 5, and at that time the messages goes straight to the DLQ, right as I wanted.

My only problem is that I need to set the maxAttempts dynamically, from a property file. The solution should be setting an interceptor, but the only fact of having one causes an error, for example when I have :

```
@Service
@EnableRetry 
public class PushService {

    @Retryable(interceptor="myInterceptor") 
    public Result pushIt(myMessage messageIn) {
        ...
    }
}
```

where myInterceptor is defined as :

```
@Bean
public StatefulRetryOperationsInterceptor myInterceptor() {
    return RetryInterceptorBuilder.stateful().maxAttempts(5).build();
}
```

I get an infinite loop with the following exception:

```
2015-04-08 07:12:10,970 GMT [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] (ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler.java:67) WARN  listener.ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler: Execution of Rabbit message listener failed.
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener threw exception
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.wrapToListenerExecutionFailedExceptionIfNeeded(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:864)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:802)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:690)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$001(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:82)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$1.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:167)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1241)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:660)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1005)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:989)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$700(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:82)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1103)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.config.StatefulRetryOperationsInterceptorFactoryBean$3.getKey(StatefulRetryOperationsInterceptorFactoryBean.java:103)
    at org.springframework.retry.interceptor.StatefulRetryOperationsInterceptor.invoke(StatefulRetryOperationsInterceptor.java:132)
    at org.springframework.retry.annotation.AnnotationAwareRetryOperationsInterceptor.invoke(AnnotationAwareRetryOperationsInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)
    at com.acme.push.service.PushService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9d503bc1.pushMessage(<generated>)
    at com.acme.push.receiver.PushListener.onMessage(PushListener.java:42)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:799)
    ... 10 more
```

I am pretty sure I am keeping it too simple, but I just have no clues on what could cause this error and how to solve it, anybody has an idea of what is going on ?

Comment: It expects at least a method with 2 arguments, with the second one of type  `org.springframework.amqp.core.Message`. I do not find why... Javadoc and reference seems to not contain any information...

Comment: Exact, I am debugging and I just saw it. Moreover, the `Message` must have a messageId property, else we'll have an exception:   `org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.FatalListenerExecutionException: Illegal null id in message. Failed to manage retry for message: ...  `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to obtain the needed flexibility without using the `@Retrayable` annotation.

I created a `RetryAdvice` with my parameters for delay and maximum number of attempts:

```
@Bean
public MethodInterceptor retryAdvice() {
    FixedBackOffPolicy backOffPolicy = new FixedBackOffPolicy();
    backOffPolicy.setBackOffPeriod(delay);
    return RetryInterceptorBuilder.stateless().backOffPolicy(backOffPolicy)
            .maxAttempts(maxAttempts).build();
}
```

and I inserted the Advice in the adviceChain of the `ListenerContainer`

```
@Bean
public SimpleMessageListenerContainer replyListenerContainer() {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(pushConnectionFactory());
    container.setQueues(pushQueue());
    container.setMessageListener(pushListener());

    Advice[] adviceChain = new Advice[] { retryAdvice() };
    container.setAdviceChain(adviceChain);

    return container;
}
```

In this way, whenever my Listener will be throwing

```
throw new AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException(cause);
```

this will cause the container to retry the indicated number of times with the desired delay, after which the exception will be propagated and the message will be delivered in the DLQ

Answer (score 4):

The purpose of `org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.config.RetryInterceptorBuilder` is not to be used using the annotation `@Retryable`.

Its purpose is to be used with the advice chain of the `SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory` class. 
See the reference documentation [receiving-messages](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.4.4.RELEASE/reference/html/amqp.html#receiving-messages) and he `SimpleMessageListenerContainer#invokeListener` signature:

```
@Override
protected void invokeListener(Channel channel, Message message) throws Exception {
    proxy.invokeListener(channel, message);
}
```

You annotation will be useless as soon as you configure the advice chain with the appropriate `RetryInterceptor`.

Comment: Thank Nicolas, but if the purpose is not to be used in a `@Retryable`, I would not expect to have a dedicated parameter in the class (see javadoc [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-retry/docs/api/current/) ) ... there should be a way to make it work... still trying to find it out :(

Comment: If you want to use the annotation with a custom Interceptor you should use the `org.springframework.retry.interceptor.RetryInterceptorBuilder` not `org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.config.RetryInterceptorBuilder`. I think the last one should only be used with `SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory` and the associated amqp classes.